# Wrong value sent in htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

People, ive got a problem with htaccess. 
Am using codeigniter as framework.
The code im currently using is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.example\.(.*+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php/main_controller/method/%1 [QSA,L]
```

Now what I wanna do is to send the %1 as a value to my 'main_controller' controller's method named 'method'. Problem : Instead of sending the value that comes in ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+), it is sending the one that comes in ([0-9]+) which should be the case if i send %2.... I wanna send the value that's coming in ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+),
Say, for example if url is

> somevalue.example.com/index33

It's sending `33` instead of `somevalue`

Comment: Your last RewriteCond is overwriting the previous, meaning $1/%1 is what ever is after /index(here)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.(.*+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php/main_controller/method/%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thankx for ur reply Nick, Now i can get somevalue but with %2 am unable to get 33. I need both of them.:( I mean, both ([^.]+) from ^([^.]+)\.example... and ([0-9]+) from index([0-9]+) are required:(

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.(.*+) [NC]
RewriteRule /index([0-9]+) /index.php/main_controller/method/%1/$1 [QSA,L]
```

So, foolish me. To get variable from URI , you dont have to put it to REQUEST_URI, just put it i Rewrite rule , the variable from RewrideCond was obtained in %1, and that of ([0-9]+) from  RewriteRule /index([0-9]+) was get in $1. Hope it helps others too